# Error in N Queens Problem using Backtracking and Recursion

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking, n-queens

I first implemented a zero matrix indicating that all the positions of the chessboard are initially available

```
n=int(input())
answer=[]
restrictedIndices=[[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
dp(n,0,restrictedIndices,answer)
```

and then I implemented three functions to fill the restrictedIndices

```
def columnFill(restrictedIndices,row,column,n):
    o=column
    restrictedIndices[row][o]=1
    while o+1<n:
        o+=1
        restrictedIndices[row][o]=1
    o=column
    while o-1>=0:
        o-=1
        restrictedIndices[row][o]=1    
    o=column
    return restrictedIndices


def rowFill(restrictedIndices,row,column,n):
    o=row
    restrictedIndices[o][column]=1
    while o+1<n:
        o+=1
        restrictedIndices[o][column]=1
    o=row
    while o-1>=0:
        o-=1
        restrictedIndices[o][column]=1
    o=row    
    return restrictedIndices


def diagonalFill(restrictedIndices,row,column,n):
    o=row
    p=column
    restrictedIndices[o][column]=1
    while o+1<n and p+1<n:
        o+=1
        p+=1
        restrictedIndices[o][p]=1
    o=row
    p=column
    while o-1>=0 and p+1<n:
        o-=1
        p+=1
        restrictedIndices[o][p]=1
    o=row
    p=column
    while o+1<n and p-1>=0:
        o+=1
        p-=1
        restrictedIndices[o][p]=1
    o=row
    p=column
    while o-1>=0 and p-1>=0:
        o-=1
        p-=1
        restrictedIndices[o][p]=1    
    o=row
    p=column
    return restrictedIndices
```

and then the recursive function

```
def dp(n,row,restrictedIndices,answer):
    print(restrictedIndices)
    if row==n:
        print("yes i got a solution")
        return -1
    print(restrictedIndices)
    for i in range(n):
        if restrictedIndices[row][i]==1:
            print("rejected",(row,i))
            continue
        
        else:
            x=[i for i in restrictedIndices]
            print(row,i)
            columnFill(restrictedIndices,row,i,n)
            rowFill(restrictedIndices,row,i,n)
            diagonalFill(restrictedIndices,row,i,n)
            dp(n,row+1,restrictedIndices,answer)
```

I am getting wrong output and I would kindly like to know if we can solve the problem this way and if there is a better alternative.
*I hope I could understand how recursion and Backtracking works through the solution*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work, because of the following issues:

- `answer` is never populated: it can therefore be nothing else than its initial value, an empty list
- Although you let `dp` return -1 when a solution is found, this value is never checked by the caller. So the caller does not know about it and goes to the next iteration of its `for` loop
- When the recursive call of `dp` returns, the `restrictedIndices` list is not returned to its previous state. This means that in the next iterations of the `for` loop the condition `[row][i]==1` will always be True -- this cell was set to 1 during the first iteration. You should make sure that each iteration of the `for` loop starts with the exact same state of `restrictedIndices`.

I will not post a working solution, as this is extensively documented on the internet, and recursive solutions for Python can be found also on Stack Overflow:

- [eight queens problem in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133509/eight-queens-problem-in-python),
- [Backtracking 8 Queens Python problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64195911/backtracking-8-queens-python-problems)
- [Solving the n-queen puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818201/solving-the-n-queen-puzzle)
- [8 Queens Solution in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715222/8-queens-solution-in-python)
- [N Queens: backtracking solution implemented by Python generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052858/n-queens-backtracking-solution-implemented-by-python-generator)